# How to move text from left to right in regex?

Tags: notepad++, regex

So I have text like this:

```
text1;text2
```

I want it to be like this:

```
text2:text1
```

I also want to replace the ";" with a ":" as you can see.

Note: I am trying to do this in Notepad++.

Comment: Will this be two items per row, for many rows in a file?

Comment: Yes, Christopher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply search for `(text1);(text2)` and replace with `$2:$1`, marking the `Regular expression` box.

In this case `text1` and `text2` can be replaced by any regular expressions which match the texts you want to match. The brackets are not matched, but mark a field in the source text, so the `$1` in the replacement is substituted with whatever source string matched the first field (and `$2` the second).

For example `(^[^;]*);(.*$)` will make the substitution on every line with a `;` in it.

Comment: Thank you, I searched for (^[^;]*);(.*$) and replaced it with $2:$1. Learned something new.